# How to connect javascript client to ams (rtmp and shared objects)

Tags: javascript, rtmp, shared-objects

I built an online card game (2008) with flash and also objective c (ipad) clients that connect to an adobe media server.

So now, as Flash is rarer and rarer in the browsers, I would like to rebuild a game client in javascript, but it seems that no javascript library are existing yet (I would be ready to buy one..), so what are my options ?

I am not using any streaming functionality but my game is using a rtmp connection and shared objects..

Should I invest time on the server, ie looking how to build a gateway (java, node.js, socket.io ??) that would connect to the ams and offer "standard sockets" for a javascript client, or should I invest time on the client, trying to rebuild the part of rtmp I need on javascript ? I think the latter would be a time killer, if possible..

Thanks!

Cyril

Comment: I don't believe it would even be possible to emulate RTMP via a browser. Your only options are http(1/2) web socket and webrtc. You can't open a raw socket in the browser.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I added webrtc to my search keywords.. currently looking at Janus webrtc gateway: any further thoughts, hints on the subject ? :)